# Apply effect of a pseudo class to all members of a class

Tags: css-selectors, css

I want to apply something like this

```
a:visited{background-color:#0F0;}
```

to **all** `<a>` tags, if **at least one** of them has been clicked.

I know how to do it using JavaScript, but is there a pure CSS version?

I doesn't have to be `<a>` or `:visited`, I just want to highlight all occurrences with a certain tag or class if just one of them gets selected/hovered.

Comment: What about your current example isn't working? Can you clarify a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too clear on the effect you want, and why you want it, but there's no way to do this with CSS, you're stuck using javascript :(

As I understand, you want to style *all* `<a>` tags if *one* has been hovered or clicked? Why not just make that the default style, it will probably only take 2 seconds until that happens.

Comment: I need to wait until I've had some coffee in me. I was rambling on about expected colors with CSS shorthand. To your example: #ecd is valid, but not the equivalent to #ecdecd - where #fff is equivalent to #ffffff.

Comment: @Dawson: Understandable. Father CSS™ forgives you :)